# Is getting any element with iterator().next() from a HashSet slower than getting them from a LinkedHashSet?

Tags: java, iterator, set, hashset, linkedhashset

I read this sentence on a [Leetcode solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/insert-delete-getrandom-o1-duplicates-allowed/discuss/85540/Java-HaspMap-LinkedHashSet-ArrayList-(155-ms)) :

> I modified the code by replacing HashSet with LinkedHashSet because
>   the set.iterator() might be costly when a number has too many
>   duplicates. Using LinkedHashSet can be considered as O(1) if we only
>   get the first element to remove.

As you can see in the comments below the solution, some people don't agree with that sentence.

Is it true that getting a random element from a set using `set.iterator().next()` is faster for `LinkedHashSet` than for a `HashSet`  and why ?

I had a little look at the implementation, is it because the `iterator` of `HashSet` browse the backing array to find a non empty cell?

Comment: If you don't really care which element you get, then any difference will be measured in microseconds.

Comment: Getting an element from a `HashSet` should also be O(1). Presumably the slowest operation is constructing the `Iterator`.

Comment: @JoeC : what if the backing array is huge and a there is not a lot of elements remaining? I don't think that HashSets/HashMaps shrink when a lot of elements is removed

Comment: Fair, but that's not really a case I come across often at all.

Comment: It is true that searching a sparse `HashSet` for the first element will be slower than getting the first element from a `LinkedHashSet`, but the cost of maintaining a `LinkedHashSet` is higher. Is the performance impact of switch from `HashSet` to `LinkedHashSet` noticeable? Only profiling with actual data can tell you that. Don't micro-optimize this, unless profiling shows a problem. Use the `Set` implementation that makes most sense to the code.